# Moving a file from host with docker-compose volume before Dockerfile is built

Tags: docker-compose, personal-access-token

I have a few Dockerfiles that are dependant on a "pat" (Personal Access Token) file to be able to access a private nuget feed. I have taken some inspiration from [somakdas](https://somakdas.medium.com/private-nuget-package-restore-in-docker-build-azure-devops-431fdfeae557) to get this working.

To run my single Dockerfile I first create a "pat" file containing my token and build with `docker build -f Services/User.API/Dockerfile -t userapi:dev --secret id=pat,src=pat .`

This works as intended, but my issue is getting this to work using a docker-compose.yml file.

First I took a look at using docker-compose secrets, but it came to my attention that docker-compose secrets are access at runtime, not build-time. https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6358

So now I'm trying to create a volume containing my pat file but I get `cat: /pat: No such file or directory` when the command `RUN --mount=type=secret...` is running. This may not be secure but it will only be running locally.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["User.API.csproj", "/Services/User.API"]

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=pat,dst=/pat export ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"<feed>\", \"username\":\"<user>\", \"password\":\"`cat /pat`\"}]}" \
&& dotnet restore "User.API.csproj" \
&& unset VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS

...
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  user.api:
    container_name: User.API
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}userapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/User.API/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app_network
    volumes:
      - ./pat:/app/src/pat
```

Am I only able to access docker-compose volumes after the Dockerfile is built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by attacking the problem in a different way. As the main goal was to get this working locally I created Dockerfile.Local and docker-compose.local.yml. Together with this I created an .env file containing the "pat".

The docker-compose.local.yml passes the "pat" as an argument to the Dockerfile.Local where it's used. I also discarded `--mount=type=secret` and set the value to `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` directly.

.env file:

```
PAT_TOKEN=<personal access token>
```

docker-compose.local.yml:

```
services:
  user.api:
    container_name: User.API
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}userapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/User.API/Dockerfile
    args:
      - PAT=${PAT_TOKEN}
    networks:
      - app_network
    volumes:
      - ./pat:/app/src/pat
```

Dockerfile.Local:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
RUN wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh | bash

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["User.API.csproj", "/Services/User.API"]

ARG PAT
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS="{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"<feed>\", \"username\":\"<user>\", \"password\":\"${PAT}\"}]}" \
&& dotnet restore "User.API.csproj" \
&& unset VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS

...
```

*Note: The .env file was added to .gitignore because it is containing sensitive information. We don't want that in our repository*.